# Markdown Not indenting first paragraph

Tags: markdown, rstudio

I am writing a report right now and the first paragraph under each section of the report is not indented while the other paragraphs are.

I'm not sure if this matters but here are the packages that are being used

```
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{rotating}
   - \usepackage{geometry}
   - \usepackage{caption,setspace}
   - \usepackage{biblatex}
   - \usepackage{bibentry}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default latex behavior because it is also what the typographic tradition usually requires for English papers. You can turn it off either by:

- specifying a language where it should be turned off (see [this answer on tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39227/no-indent-in-the-first-paragraph-in-a-section)). For instance:

  ```
  ---
  lang: french
  ---
  ```
- force indentation of the first paragraph with package `indentfirst`

  ```
  ---
  header-includes:
     - \usepackage{indentfirst}
  ---
  ```